# How to get data from Cursor associated with GridView

Tags: android

I have GridView and using SimpleCursorAdapter with it to show data from database.
I want to get data which associated with current element when I clicked to item on GridView. How I can do it?
That's my Adapter code:

```
public class ReceiptAdapter  extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
private Context context;
private Cursor cursor;
private int layout;
private Map<Object,String> receipt_id_cursor_id=new HashMap<Object,String>();

//public ReceiptAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Receipt> receiptValues) {
public ReceiptAdapter(Context _context, int _layout, Cursor _cursor, String[]         _from, int[] _to){    
    super(_context, _layout, _cursor, _from, _to);
    cursor = _cursor;
    layout = _layout;
    this.context = _context;
}

@Override
public View newView(Context _context, Cursor _cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) _context.getSystemService(_context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     View view  = inflater.inflate(layout, null);
     return view;
}


@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context _context, Cursor _cursor) {

receipt_id_cursor_id.put(_cursor.getPosition(), _cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(ReceiptEntry.COLUMN_NAME_RECEIPT_NAME))) ;  

 TextView textView = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
 textView.setText(_cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(ReceiptEntry.COLUMN_NAME_RECEIPT_NAME)));
    // set image based on selected text
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);

    imageView.setImageResource(App.getInstance().getResources().getIdentifier(_cursor.getString(_cursor.getColumnIndex(ReceiptEntry.COLUMN_NAME_IC_NAME)) , 
                            "drawable", App.getInstance().getPackageName()));
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    //return receiptValues.size()-1;
    return cursor.getCount();
}


@Override
public Cursor getItem(int position) {
    //return receiptValues.get(position);
     return this.getCursor();

    //return cursor;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return cursor.getPosition();
    //return position;
}
```

When bindView is working I see that cursor change it position. But when I pressed to item I don't know what method give me current position of cursor. For example in public long getItemId(int position)i get argument "position" that show me current position in grid.

Answer (score 0):

In **public long getItemId(int position) method** write the below code.

```
cursor.moveToPosition(position);
```

then in your listener access your cursor directly.

Comment: Is "position" every time same for current element position in GridView and in cursor?